# Is there a map data structure that allows for object keys that are unique by logical equality vs reference equality?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, data-structures

I'm looking for any kind of information regarding a data structure that will allow me to do the following operation.

```
// I assume a data structure like this would be called DeepMap
var map = new DeepMap();

// The key is a deep JS object
map.set({this: {is: 'a key'}}, 'value');

// Notice that we retrieve the value using a key that is not equal to the
// original key by reference. However, it is logically equal.
map.get({this: {is: 'a key'}) === 'value'; // true
```

One caveat: It must not simply hash the entire contents of the object to turn it into a string key.

Any pointers in the right direction? I'm programming in JS but not necessarily looking for a JS specific answer. Thanks!

Comment: There is not. You would need to implement your own DeepMap and with set and get, hash the entire contents into a string key. (at least in js)

Comment: @juvian I'm ok with implementing my own DeepMap (I wasn't looking for a built-in data structure) but do you mean that something like this would be impossible without hashing the contents of the object key?

Comment: Either hash them to string or keep them as obj and then in the get you would need to check against all keys if the 2 objects are logically equal, which means a recursive function to check if their structure and values are the same

Comment: An algorithm to do efficiently the recursive check against all existing keys in the set is exactly what I'm looking for. That's ok if there are no known strategies for that, I just wanted to be sure.

Comment: Will your set and get always be objects? And will they always be just string-value pairs or they can have another object as keys?